# Uploading a PDF File From Swift Yields a Blank PDF

Tags: swift, pdf, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, alamofire

Im trying to upload a PDF generated from a UIImage.  I take a picture using my camera framework, uploads all ok but the PDF on S3 is blank.  Below is the code I am using:

1. I use the following class to create the PDF from a UIImage, tested ok.

```
    // Using PDFKit
    func generatePDF(source: UIImage) -> PDFDocument {
    
      let pdfDocument = PDFDocument()
      let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: source)
      pdfDocument.insert(pdfPage!, at: 0)
      return pdfDocument
    }
```

2. I used Alamofire to perform a multipart upload with the pdf, tested ok.

```
class NetworkManager {
    
    static let shared = NetworkManager()
    
    func upload(document: Data, name: String) {
        
        let filename = "\(name).pdf"
        let urlString = endpoint + "?filename=" + filename
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 30)
        request.method = .post
        request.setValue(key, forHTTPHeaderField: api)
        AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
            multiPart.append(document, withName: name, fileName: filename, mimeType: "application/pdf")
        }, with: request)
            .uploadProgress(queue: .main, closure: { progress in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { data in
                print("data: \(data)")
            })
    }
}
```

3. On AWS I am using the following framework to reconstruct the multipart data back to a PDF

lambda-multipart-parser
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-multipart-parser

How Im using it in Lambda:

```
    let filename = event.queryStringParameters.filename;
    let documentData = await imageParser.parse(event);
    let document = documentData.files[0];

    var data = {
        Bucket: 'order-scanned-copy',
        Key: filename,
        Body: document.content,
        ContentType: "application/pdf",
      };
      
    let uploadFile = await s3.putObject(data).promise();
```

No errors, no warnings just a blank PDF. I can tell by the size around 500kb-1mb that it has something in it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you write the PDF document into the data that you upload?  Where you say "tested ok" does that mean that you've looked at the content of the PDF file that is generated and verified that the PDF is generated properly to begin with?

Comment: What is the guy named 'api'?  How are you converting your PDF file into a `Data` object?  Where are you uploading data?

Comment: What happends if you try uploading a JPEG image by making its `Data` object with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`?

Comment: I used breakpoints to inspect the creation of the pdf object, opened it saved it def a valid pdf.

Comment: 'api' is a variable for the api-header.  I could have used a better name.  I am using data representation on a PDF Document to generate the data object.  Im using alamofire's multipart upload function, this part:   ```multiPart.append(document, withName: name, fileName: filename, mimeType: "application/pdf")```

Comment: El Tomato, Im trying that next.

Comment: El Tomato, tried doing the same but with a UIImage and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, since I am using AWS specifically API Gateway and Lambda I needed to add the "Binary Media Type" to API Gateway.  To do this I opened Api Gateway console and choose my API. Then, selected Settings and added the following types.

[image: Image of Binary Media Types Added]

I did a redeploy of my api and everything worked perfect, so in the end it was not a code problem but configuration mistake on AWS.

This blog post was very helpful:
[AWS SAM Configuration for API Gateway Binary Response / Payloads](https://medium.com/@jun711.g/aws-sam-configuration-for-api-gateway-binary-response-payloads-9da4337c3c4a)

Thanks for your help everyone.